# Recording Lenovo Easy Camera with ffmpeg - framerate too low

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, video-conversion, audio-recording

Does anybody have a glue why I can't get ffmpeg to record my webcam higher than 8 fps, with ffmpeg? I've tried Cheese and GUVCView, under various settings, but all I get is a still picture. I'm obviously doing this in Linux.

I've tried to force the framerate to 30fps, but then the resulting recording is at the wrong speed, too fast, like in a slapstick movie from the twenties.

My ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -f v4l2 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -i /dev/video0 -c:a copy -b:v 2000k output.mkv`

I thought I might record a video in the Web Camera application in Windows 10 - which works - examine the resulting video in ffmpeg, and try to mimick the codecs somehow. However I'm lost at how I can do that.

This is how ffmpeg describes the Windows recording:

`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'prufaLenCam_160223.mp4':`
  `Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2016-02-23 07:56:11`
  `Duration: 00:00:28.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8116 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7949 kb/s, 29.69 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)`
    `Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-23 07:56:11
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding`
    `Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)`
    `Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-02-23 07:56:11
      handler_name    : SoundHandler`
`No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.`
`Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.`

Output from the Linux ffmpeg command tried:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15185929/

Comment: Please show the **complete** console output from your `ffmpeg` command and not just an excerpt, and also show the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`.

Comment: Just edited my question to include the output. I don't have `v412-ctl` installed. I believe the key was to use the `mjpeg` codec - see my own answer below. After I found out how to record my webcam in VLC, I think I even prefer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research, and believe I've solved the issue with this command:

`ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -f v4l2 -c:v mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -t 30 -b:v 2000k test.mp4`

Based on [the information here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119827/how-do-i-record-audio-and-video-to-a-file-from-my-webcam-using-ffmpeg?rq=1) - the last comment from the author of the question, but adapted for my own system and preferences.